# Generic way to know whether a laptop is located in the office or not?

Tags: vnc

I develop software running laptops from various companies. The employees are allowed to bring these laptops home or on holidays. I want to be able to reliably detect whether the laptops are in the office or not. The laptops are connected to the company network via some kind of VPN (though various solutions are used), so I cannot say that if they can access internet, they are in the office. To make this question even more interesting, please notice that a company might have multiple locations.

Edit: I need to detect this on the laptop.

Comment: @Pabuc in these times with workaholics, one cannot know whether the person is still in the office at 2 am. ;) This is especially true for system administrators.

Comment: And if I catch the flu and still work from home, it will be at 2 PM. Nope, time is not enough.

Comment: Do you really mean at the Office and at Home or at the Office/Not at the Office? What would be a holidayhome? At home? At the office? Or other? Where do you want to detect it? physcical on the laptop or remote by grooming the logfiles of routers, directories, application servers?

Comment: @rene. You are right. I have updated the question. I want to do this on the laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer from Rob is close but maybe you should take into account the gateway used by the NIC.

And if you have time enough a tracert to a known server in your office.

That will give you the route and the intermediate NIC's between the laptop and the known server.

You only have to make sure in that case that on the office location the route to the VPN concentrator is different but that should be possible with a clever dns/dhcp setup.

You might try a more specific question on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Speculation:  One thing you could look at are the IP addresses allocated to the machine.  If you run a VPN then at home then there is probably one IP for the Internet connection and one for the VPN.

Comment: If it works, it would be a good idea. But it is not normal that one goes on the internet via the VPN? Isn't that why one can go on things like http://intranet/ also when at home?

Comment: I think this answer is close but maybe you should take into account the gateway used by the NIC. And if you have time enough a tracert to a known server in your office. That will give you the route and the intermediate NIC's between the laptop and the known server. You only have to make sure in that case that on the office location the route to the VPN concentrator is different but that should be possible with a clever dns/dhcp setup. You might try a more specific question on serverfault.com

Comment: @rene Tracert is a great idea. Something should always show up there, if no simpler way shows up, I think I will go for that (just make it an answer).

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done reliably, because branch offices can be setup up the same as a home network. And from experience, I'm not saying "almost the same as a home network". I mean literally the same, with non-clued managers buying network equipment from the cheapest local shop, and running copies of Windows XP HOME.

Comment: I understand. What would be a best guess then, if I have to accept that it cannot be done 100% reliably.

Comment: The most common solution is to solve the _actual_ problem. This appears a classic XY problem. You have got a business problem X which you know to translate into a home/office question Y. We can't solve Y, but if you'd told us about X we might solve that.

Comment: I know it sounds like an XY problem, but it is not. Explaining all the details so you could confirm this, would simply be exhausting.